# How do I find/select xpath of following web element?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Problem Statement:** I have been facing the issue for selecting following web element. (Actually these are the texts)

**HTML Code:**

```
    <tr class="inputtextfields" bgcolor="#CDDBE9">
                <td width="12%" height="25">
                    <div align="center">Firstname1234Lastname</div></td> 
    <tr class="inputtextfields" bgcolor="#CDDBE9">     
    <td width="12%" height="25"> <div align="center">Firstname45671Lastname</div></td>
```

**What am I looking for?**

I am looking for the locating **"Firstname1234Lastname"** element or text by Web Driver using `Java` language. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: share your code and specify problems you've faced with your code

Comment: I am using the absolute XPATH to select the element and it's working fine but as we all aware of we should be using 'Relative XPATH' or something better and unique. If the structure of the web page changes then my absolute xpath will not work. I am looking for help to build relative xpath.

Comment: It's hard to suggest good selector with provided `HTML` sample. Can you share more ancestors?

Comment: I have updated the code. Now I want to select "Firstname1234Lastname". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below `XPath` to locate required elements:

```
"(//tr[@class='inputtextfields']/td/div)[1]" // For "Firstname1234Lastname"
```

and

```
"(//tr[@class='inputtextfields']/td/div)[2]" // For "Firstname45671Lastname"
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your issue. Thanks